How to automatically migrate replicas to other nodes after a Kafka replica node has been down for a period of time
When a node goes down and remains down for several hours, I notice that the failed replicas are not automatically migrated to other healthy nodes. When hardware failures occur, I have to manually rebalance all the failed replicas to other nodes. Does Kafka have a mechanism to achieve automatic migration in such cases?
I tried looking for an automated solution, but I couldn’t find a suitable method.

You'll need to write your own script to handle the "after amount of time" piece. Kafka comes with no automated process for this; you'll have to manually execute kafka-reassign-partitions with healthy broker id details.
You can try looking into CruiseControl for administrative tasks, but I'm not sure how it handles broker outages during rebalancing tasks
